# Protecting from malicious zip files with vbscript and file association change

Tags: zip, vbscript

I think it would be useful to pass zip files to a VBscript script that would pop up a warning to the user that they are opening a potentially dangerous file and give them the option unzip or not.

I know I could redirect the .zip files association to a vbscript program, but I'm not sure how to pass the name of the file clicked on to that script.  Any help would be appreciated.

T

Comment: We are not a VB script writting service.  So what have you tried exactly?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is exactly the task for an antivirus.

If you plan on creating your own antivirus, which I strongly discourage, then you will need to use much more sophisticated techniques to protect the system from risky files.

If your intention is to get a better antivirus which has options to do analyze file archives, then you should look at the different products specifications, or try the most popular ones until you find one that works like you want.

Most antiviruses will check the content of a `zip` archive.

For safe testing, refer to the [`EICAR`](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) test file.